# How to group using RegEx (complex string)

Tags: regex

Consider the following string:

```
sarga erhaerh<bar>gwegw</bar>wegweg<bar>aeg seg</bar>rgweg
```

I need this to be grouped like this:

```
group 1: sarga erhaerh
group 2: <bar>gwegw</bar>
group 3: wegweg
group 4: <bar>aeg seg</bar>
group 5: rgweg
```

This string can be any combination of text in combination with the `<bar>` element. Its not so hard to extract the bar element, checkout the solution [here](https://regex101.com/r/cF2kO7/1)

Any suggestions how I can expand this so it will match the other parts as well ?

Comment: I would use a DOM parser for that

Comment: its backend / java so I'm not sure if that is the easiest / best solution!

Comment: What language do you use? I am curious wheather you can use perl/basic regexp?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri  I bet Java has the most elaborated DOM stack of all programming languages. (Even most reference implementations are in Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(<bar>.*?</bar>|.+?(?=(?:<bar>|\z)))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cZ1qN4/7)

**Explanation:**

```
<bar>.*?</bar>   # Match text from <bar> to </bar>
|                # alternation (OR) of regex
.+?              # match one or more of any characters *if*
(?=              # start of positive lookahead
  <bar>          # Match literal text <bar> or
  |              # alternation  
  \z             # end of line
)                # end of positive lookahead
```

In other words we're trying to match either:

- text between `<bar>` and `</bar>` OR
- text outside `<bar>` and `</bar>`

Comment: What exactly does the `(?=(?:<bar>|\z))` part do. Because when I remove it, it still seems to match all situations [example](https://regex101.com/r/cZ1qN4/6)

Comment: I should have included better example of the regex. See my updated answer and updated demo. This won't work without lookahead i.e. your regex: `(<bar>.*?</bar>|[^<>]+)`

Comment: I now understand why you have `(?=(?:<bar>|\z))` But can you give an example in which `(<bar>.*?</bar>|.+?)` will mach incorrect. I tried, but couldn't find one!

Comment: [`(<bar>.*?</bar>|.+?)` will match too little, see here](https://regex101.com/r/cZ1qN4/8) in the **MATCH INFORMATION** section

Comment: I see now, its the grouping, thnx!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^([a-z\s]*)(<bar>.*?<\/bar>)([a-z])*(<bar>.*?<\/bar>)([a-z]+)$`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cF2kO7/2

Comment: this will not work if the string has a different structure (<bar>...</bar and text at different places)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I misunderstood the question a bit.